# Issue with Posted JSON data to Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a web page which posts data to an Web API.
The ajax function is as follows.

```
 var jsondata = { "comparisionCalculatorReq": { "transactionType": "None", "fundName": "Myfund", "annualizedReturn": "10", "frequency": "Monthly"} };  

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "http://localhost:1101/Mypost/PostDataAPI",  
dataType: 'json',  
data: jsondata  
}).done(function (msg) {  
alert(msg);  
});
```

In my Web API controller i have a method as below

```
[ActionName("PostDataAPI")]  
       public string PostDataAPI(JSONdata obj)  
       {  
           try  
           {  
               string k = obj.transactionType;  
               return k;  
           }  
           catch (Exception err)  
           {  
               throw err;  
           }  
       }
```

The JSONdata class is below

```
public class JSONdata  
   {  
       public string transactionType { get; set; }  
       public string fundName { get; set; }  
       public string annualizedReturn { get; set; }  
       public string frequency { get; set; }  
   }
```

Problem is that, I'm getting null value for transactionType in my controller.

If the json data is passed like this in ajax,

```
var jsondata={ "transactionType": "None", "fundName": "Myfund", "annualizedReturn": "10", "frequency": "Monthly"};
```

then all the values are got correct.
Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have your solution: use the correct AJAX representation of your query model.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that when the object i'm passing in the format as provided in the top part of question, i can't access the values from it in my api. But if it is passed like the one given below in the question, i'm able to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Changed the model class as below

```
 public class JSONdata
{
    public comparisionCalculatorReq[] comparisionCalculatorReq { get; set; }
}
public class comparisionCalculatorReq
{
    public string transactionType { get; set; }
    public string fundName { get; set; }
    public string annualizedReturn { get; set; }
    public string frequency { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper `Content-Type` header and also transform your javascript object into a JSON string by using the `JSON.stringify` method:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://localhost:1101/Mypost/PostDataAPI",  
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsondata)
}).done(function (msg) {  
    alert(msg);  
});
```